# How to render a specific object within an array, when clicking on a component, in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

[Codesandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/jd-fillmore/ff7-dex/tree/development)

Okay, so the high level functionality of what I want this app to do:

1. Upon load, you're presented with the characters on the left, and on the right an intro screen.
2. When a user clicks on the first character (Cloud) for example, then the intro screen is replaced with Cloud's stats. If a user clicks on the second, third, etc character, same thing. The intro screen on the right is replaced with that character's specific stats.

That's basically it. I'm finding it really tough to do, for some reason.

For the /components/ folder breakdown (I'll go over the important ones):

- /components/content/ - this is where the characters information lives, housed in the State. Each character is uniquely identified by an 'id'.
- /components/sidebar/ - this is the sidebar component
- /components/card-overview/ - this is a single component, repeated a few times, that houses the 'overview' of each character (image, character name), that you see in the sidebar itself
- /components/card-detailed/ - this is where it grabs the array of objects from /components/content/, filters through and maps the character you're currently seeing to the DOM. Problem is, on line 13 of this component, you'll see I've hard-coded in the id #. Obviously, I want this to change to whatever character the user clicks, it then loads THAT character's info to the DOM. I just don't know how to do that.

In short, what I'm trying to do:

- When a character on the left is clicked, hide whatever is on the right and replace it with that character's information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: Your app has a state. For instance: `this.state = { content: -1 }`. In your render function, HTML is generated based on the state. A click on a character changes the app's state, which causes a re-render. That's how react works, at a basic level. Also, you're storing fixed character data in your Content component's state, which is not at all how it's supposed to work. state is precisely the thing that changes during the app, that's why it's named "state", not "data".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made your intention working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2lqm76z0q

As Chris pointed out, the way to go is using react state. 
Therefore, I introduced a state with the default selected item 4 and created a handleClick function that should fire once you click on one item in your sidebar. Both of them got created in App.js:

```
  state = {
    selected: 4
  };

  handleClick = id => {
    this.setState({ selected: id });
  };
```

Now, I transferred the handleClick function where it is needed, in this case in Sidebar.js:

```
<Sidebar onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

And the currently selected item needs to be transferred to your content (again, where it is needed).

```
<Content selected={this.state.selected} />
```

In the sidebar, I send the handleClick function again to the it's child, CardOverview, with the related id(*):

```
<CardOverview
  image={cloudImage}
  name="Cloud Strife"
  onClick={() => this.props.onClick(1)}
/>
```

And in CardOverview, finally, we use that function we passed down the road:

```
<section className="card-overview" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
...
</section>
```

(Whether it is working or not, we see in the console - when clicking on on item, it should show the state with the currently selected item id.)

Now, in content.js, we use the `selected` value and pass it down to CardDetailed where we use it in the following way:

```
// Grab the 'characters' object from App.js, and assign it to 'this.props'
const { characters, selected } = this.props;

// Filter the chracters and return only whose 'id' belongs to that of the selected one
const filteredCharacters = characters
  .filter(character => character.id === selected)
  .map(character => (
     <div className="characters" key={character.id}>
       <p>Name: {character.Name}</p>
       <p>Job: {character.Job}</p>
       <p>Age: {character.Age}</p>
       <p>Weapon: {character.Weapon}</p>
       <p>Height: {character.Height}</p>
       <p>Birthdate: {character.Birthdate}</p>
       <p>Birthplace: {character.Birthplace}</p>
       <p>Bloodtype: {character.Bloodtype}</p>
       <p>Description: {character.Description}</p>
      </div>
));
...
```

That`s it.

(*) Be aware, I did not improve your code, I just made it working. I see several issues that you should tackle. E.g. it is not needed to list all the characters in your sidebar manually. I'd suggest to create a file that contains your list of characters and use it in sidebar and in content. This way, you will reduce your code and maintain your characters list (and all belonging information like id) in one file.

Comment: Thank you so much!! 

I'm going line by line and trying to really grasp everything you've suggest. I love how you break it out line by line and explain it.

Some parts are a bit confusing to me, but obviously it works. I'll absolutely take your suggestions and try refactoring my code. Seriously though, even though I don't quite understand your solution fully, and how you came to knowing exactly where to put things, I really appreciate this!!